# Problems updating Python from the repositories today (Feb 25, 2021)

Tags: updates, repository

> NOTE: This is a Master Canonical Post for the issues observed on February 25, 2020.  All issues on Feb 25 relating to Python updates not found should be dupe-linked here.

Errors have been seen such as this today, February 25, 2021:

```
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7-minimal_2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb 404 Not Found
```

Is there something up with the repositories?

Answer (score 0):

**This is a known issue** that happened today, February 25, 2020.

There was an emergency case where the archives were out of sync.  To quote the Mirrors team:

> we know about the missing python 2.7 packages.  We had to react quickly to a serious regression, and should be publishing normally soon.

Regression information is not available, however, but we can safely state that this was because they yanked the bad packages out *fast* before things propagated, and then the sync systems got up to date after they fixed the regression.

As of around 11:30AM UTC-5, the archives should be syncing properly and this issue should be "resolved" now automatically.